# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments

Tags: python-3.x, django

I cannot register a new user due to below error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uid64': 'Mjk', 'token': 'aydhbh-1b0354ce0dd3df37193a6f22e95b0c4e'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/activate/(?P<uidb64>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<token>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.account_register, name='register'),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.account_activate, name='activate'),
    # User dashboard
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
def account_register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            # Setup email
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Active your account'
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)
            return HttpResponse('Registered successfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})


def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_encode(uidb64))
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

account_activation_email.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.user_name }},

    Your account has been successfully created. Please click below link to activate your account.

    http://{{ domain }}{% url 'account:activate' uid64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

A new user is registered to a DB but as you can see there an error [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq7MX.png)
Do you guys know what is wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are missing comma: `{% url 'account:activate' uid64=uid,token=token %}`

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the first slug name :

```
urlpatterns = [
        Path ('activate / <slug: uidb64> / <slug: token> /', views.account_activate, name = 'enable'),
]
```

The first name of the slug is `uidb64`, but in the `account_activation_email.html`  you try to assign `uid64‍‍‍`

Rename `uidb64` in URLs to `uid64`:

```
urlpatterns = [
        Path ('activate / <slug: uid64> / <slug: token> /', views.account_activate, name = 'enable'),
]
```

Comment: How could I miss that! Thanks a lot!